# What's the "context" in "TypeError ... cannot be accessed in this context"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

In trying to solve my own problem that I asked about [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904666/validation-of-controlled-component-in-abstract-form-with-react-hook-form), I added some console debugging statements:

```
return ( 
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    key={headline + '_' + name + '_' + i}
    defaultValue=''
    render={({ field, formState, fieldState }) => { 
      console.log('field is');
      console.dir(field, { depth: null});
      console.log('formState is');
      console.dir(formState, { depth: null});
      console.log('fieldState is');
      console.dir(fieldState, { depth: null});
      return React.cloneElement(item.component, { 
        inputRef: field.ref,
        error: !!fieldState.error,
        helperText: fieldState.error?.message,
        FormHelperTextProps: { error: true } 
      })
    }}
  />
);
```

If I drill into what that outputs, I see

```
[Log] field is (src_Login_js.chunk.js, line 395)
[Log] Object (src_Login_js.chunk.js, line 396)
  name: "username"
  onBlur: function()
  onChange: function()
  ref: function()
    arguments: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.
    caller: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.
    length: 1
    name: ""
    Function Prototype
  value: ""
```

What I want to know is, does the context refer to my `console.log`s, or is that an actual error in the render props which I should further investigate?

Comment: This happens to every *function* that you're logging. It has nothing to do with react. Also use strict mode (so that you'll get a proper exception when attempting to access `.arguments` or `.caller`)

Comment: That's unfortunate — was hoping I had found an actual error :) As to strict mode, if I add 'use strict', it complains that it's unnecessary inside of modules, and the whole App is wrapped in `React.StrictMode`. But thanks, I'll continue looking elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I meant `'use strict';` (not react strict mode), not in your component file but where the `field.ref` function is defined

Comment: Ah, ok. `field.ref` comes from  the `react-hook-form` library, so not much to be done about that.